# Delete a checkin via the API

Tags: foursquare

Via the website a user can go to their history and manually delete a checkin. Is it possible to do this via the API as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible via the API.

Since there's no way to un-delete a check-in, we wanted to protect users from loosing all their foursquare history due to a bug in a 3rd-party app. Many delete actions are actually not exposed through the API for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible according to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/foursquare-api/BADu3GYFhwI) on Google Groups. The [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) does not seem to have anything about checkin deletion either, rather just deleting items from lists, venue groups or comments.